# What title should claimant to have to remain my vassal after supporting his claim?

Tags: crusader-kings-2

I'm a king of Norway and England, have a courtier who is a bishop of Norwich, which is in Norfolk county. This Bishop has 3 claims: one on a Duchy of Britany, another on a Kingdom of Breizh, and on a county of Tregor. And we are not of the same dynasty. And I'm not de jure liege of those titles.

I don't understand the mechanic well. If I support either of his claims, he will NOT remain my vassal and own either Dutchy or Kingdom. Am I correct?

What if I give him a duchy title to one of my own duchies, will this make a difference?

How can I become de jure liege of those titles so I can benefit from supporting those claims?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

if your vassal gets a title that's lower than your primary title, he will remain your vassal.
If you press a claim for someone of your dynasty and the unlanded kin gets a title lower than your primary title, they wil become your vassal.
The only thing to consider is that mayors who get a duchy will make them a republic.
In your situation, you want to press the claim on the duchy, not on the kingdom.

Comment: Khm, had the case yesterday, I am a king of Norway, England, and Wales. I had a vassal with the claim on some land in Ireland, pushed it, conquered,... and got my former vassal independent.
ATM I don't remember exactly if my vassal was landed or not. The vassal was not from my dynasty, and I guess he was not landed and that's why he became independent?

Comment: @Budda Yes, you need to give them a landed title in your realm, he was only your courtier, most likely.

Answer (score 3):

As long as you press a claim for someone who is your direct or indirect vassal, that person will remain your vassal.

In the case of the bishop, the claimant will remain your vassal as long as the claimed title is lower than your rank. If you're a duke and press a claim for a duchy, the new duke will go independent - so be careful.

A thing to note, if the bishop becomes a count or duchy level title holder, the county or duchy will become a Metropolitan or Prince-Bishopic respectively. Those kind of landholders provide lots of piety but very little taxes (since the money goes to the religious leader usually)

Comment: It was mentioned in another comment that vassal can get independent if his new title becomes the same as yours or higher. Can you confirm that?

Comment: @Budda I have already confirmed that in my post " the claimant will remain your vassal as long as the claimed title is lower than your rank. If you're a duke and press a claim for a duchy, the new duke will go independent". So yes, if you push a claim that is at the same level or higher than your rank, the claimant goes independent.

Comment: @Budda You're welcome, happy conquering!